# Let $V$ be vector space of countable dimension over field $K$. Is it true that $V\cong V\oplus V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, vector-space-isomorphism

I know that my question has been answered on StackExchange for the countably ***infinite*** case. I understand why this holds. However, I'm reading "A course in homological algebra" by Hilton,Stammbach and they assert in an exercise that $V\cong V\oplus V$ holds for countable dimensional (so possibly ***finite***) vector spaces. I can't see why or even if this claim is true.

Please help if you have any idea if this is true or not.

Comment: They must mean "countably infinite" when they say countable. Some people do this.

Comment: @DaveWasHere Could you post a link with the answer for the infinite case? Thanks!

Comment: This post was essentially a (multi)duplicate: [Dimension of Direct sum of same Vector Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601238).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a finite-dimensional $V$ it is obviously wrong because $\dim(V \oplus V) = 2 \dim V > \dim V$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. At least I'm not crazy... So surely for the authors "countable = countably infinite".

Comment: Yes, as Randall said.

Comment: This post was essentially a (multi)duplicate: [Dimension of Direct sum of same Vector Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601238).